# Can encrypted column values be retrieved via the SOAP API in Salesforce?

Tags: api, salesforce

I am creating a java application.  I'm using the salesforce api ([example here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_quickstart_steps.htm)) to retrieve sensitive data from Salesforce.  All the data is retrieved easily except for data from the encrypted columns.  It always comes back as null.  I do have permission to view encrypted data.

Is there a restriction on the api that prevents encrypted data from being sent?

Answer (score 0):

I received the following response from Salesforce:

> In order to resolve the issue, you need to clone the System Admin Profile and assign that profile to a desired user.  After that you shall need to take the session Id of the that user who have Clone profile and use this session Id in your desired code or Tools for the API.
>
> Note:If you are using System Admin profile session Id ,you will no retrieve the Encrypted values.Only the cloned Profile can retrieve the values.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that your profile has enabled these permission: "View Encrypted Data" and "Modify All Data" permission?

Comment: I can confirm it.  I had also tried doing a fresh clone of System Admin profile adding appropriate permissions and that did not work either.